# Windows XP command prompt doesn't stay till program ends

Tags: windows, command-line, codeblocks, command-prompt

Currently,I'm working on Windows XP service pack 2. Whenever I build a C or C++ program with `Code::Blocks v16.01` and run that program outside `Code::Blocks` (e.g.: I run my compiled program clicking on the .exe file), a command prompt like window appears just showing the first input line (if it has anything at the first line of the source code) and then suddenly closes without showing any result.

I've tried several steps configuring the GNU GCC compiler in the "toolchain executable" tab, but nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried to put a `system("pause");` at the end of the program (before the return line)?

Comment: Nope.Let me try :)

Comment: @user3079834 Thanks a lot..... it works... :)

Comment: Do you know how to do this in Python 3.x? I've tried `input()` , `raw_input` ,
`time.sleep()` . But none of them works :(
like c++, is there any effective code?

Comment: Try to read for an input (like let the user give you some text)